# Let $f:\{1,..,n\} \to \{1,..,m\}$ be a function.If f is injective and $n=m$, does it follows that f is surjective ? If so, prove it.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $f:\{1,..,n\} \to \{1,..,m\}$ be a function.If f is injective and
>   $n=m$, does it follows that f is surjective ? If so, prove it.

Intuitively, is f is one-to-one, there for every $y \in \{1,..,m\}$, there is unique $x \in \{1,..,n\}$, and since n=m, is should be surjective, but I don't know exactly how transform this idea into a formal proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if it isn't surjective?  Then the $n$ elements in your domain get mapped to $n-1$ (or fewer) elements in your codomain, and this happens injectively.  This should be a contradiction.  Can you see why?

Hint:

> The Pidgeonhole Principle should help you derive a contradiction.

Comment: if n element is mapped to n-1(or fewer) than how can the function be injective ?

Comment: @Leth that's the contradiction.  We assumed that $f$ isn't surjective, so there's at least one element in the range that has nothing mapped to it.  So, all the $n$ elements get mapped to $n-1$ elements (as if they went to all $n$ elements $f$ would be surjective).  But then the function is no longer injective, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: why n-1 or less ? we assumed n=m

Comment: Yes.  But, to show that $f$ is surjective, we first assume that it isn't.  If $f$ isn't surjective, what does that mean?

Comment: I get it that we are proving it by contradiction but the statement is in the form (f is injective) $\wedge (n=m) \to$ (f is surjective)  , so if we want to use that method we are assuming (f is injective) $\wedge (n=m) \wedge \neg$(f is surjective) , or any other equivalent.In this light of this knowledge, I still don't get it .

Comment: Think about what it means to be surjective.  If $f$ is surjective, then for anything in the codomain of $f$, we have that an element of the domain maps to it.  So, if $f$ ISNT surjective, there HAS to exist some element $x_0$ in the codomain that no element of the domain maps to.  So, even though $f$ is mapping an $n$ element set into an $n$ element set, because it isn't mapping anything to $x_0$, it's actually just mapping an $n$ element set into an $n-1$ element set.  But we have that $f$ is injective, so the pidgeonhole principle gives a contradiction.

Comment: Ok now I get it :). Thanks.